# How to implement an interface with functions sharing the same logic?

Tags: oop, go, design-patterns, interface

I'd like to provide multiple implementations for the following interface:

```
type API interface {
    A()
    B()
    C()
}
```

According to my use cases, all implementations should share the exact same logic for function **A** and **B** while function **C** will have different logic for different implementations.

So I've created the following common implementation to be embedded:

```
type Common struct {}

func (c *Common) A() {}
func (c *Common) B() {}
```

To create two implementations for the interface above, I can just do the following:

```
type FirstImpl struct { Common }

func (i *FirstImpl) C() {}

type SecondImpl struct { Common }

func (i *SecondImpl) C() {}
```

Everything works just fine until I find out that function **C** needs to be called inside function **B**. Note that the logic for function **B** should still be the same across two implementations despite that we may get different results calling **C** inside **B**.

I'm wondering if this is a common pattern in Go and if there is an elegant way to handle it.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/8EtJWUmtryN this is one way, but I wouldn't call it elegant.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! This is very close to what I want. Ideally, I'd like to instantiate the object simply like &FirstImpl{}, without impl.Common.c = impl being repeated for every implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to emulate late binding.

One way to achieve this is by using a function pointer, and constructors for implementations:

```
type CommonImpl struct {
   cimpl func()
}

func (c CommonImpl) C() { c.cimpl() }

type FirstImpl struct {
   CommonImpl
}

func NewFirstImpl() APIImpl {
   ret:=FirstImpl{}
   ret.cimpl=ret.c
   return &ret
}
```

With this implementation, you can call the derived-type `C()`.

An alternative would be to pass the function as an argument:

```
func (c CommonImpl) C(bfunc func()) {
}

...
x:=FirstImpl{}
x.C(x.B)
```

Or with an interface:

```
type BIntf interface {
   B()
}

func (c CommonImpl) C(b BIntf) {
}


x:=FirstImpl{}
x.C(x)
```

Comment: I think it is more or less the same idea as suggested by @mkopriva in the comment above.